# Remove a part of a list of names

Tags: windows-7, batch-rename

I have some files and each files have distinct name but all of them have the same "-statement" at the end like this:

```
flower-statement.mp3
leave-statement.mp3 
ball-statement.mp3
goal-statement.mp3
```

So I want to remove this: `-statement`

Is that possible?

Comment: You want to edit a text file containing a list of names or to rename the actual files?

Comment: rename actual file

Comment: Total commander has a very nice multi-rename feature

Comment: I don't know why I didn't realize these were files and not a list of names in a file.

Comment: @Insane maybe I don't describe the question in the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just do this with batch like so without any special programs? From what I tested, this will do exactly what you're looking for it to do which is parse out the `-statement` part of the file name and then rename each without it leaving the other parts of the file. This will work for all `.mp3` files in a specific folder just fine.

In my below example where I have the `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\*.mp3` just put your folder name in that location. Save that to a text file and rename to `batch.cmd` or something like that.  Then just double-click to run it to perform the rename of the files in that folder parsing out the `-statement` part of it.

You can also make this script implicit to run the directory which you copy it to and just using `*.mp3` from there rather than the full path.

**EXPLICIT SCRIPT (specify the directory where *.mp3 are located)**

```
@ECHO ON

FOR %%A IN ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\*.mp3") DO (
    CALL :RenameFiles "%%~A" "%%~NXA"
)
GOTO EOF

:RenameFiles
SET fname=%~2
SET renname=%fname:-statement=%
REN "%~1" "%renname%"
GOTO EOF
```

**IMPLICIT SCRIPT (copy to and then run from the directory where *.mp3 are located)**

```
@ECHO ON

FOR %%A IN ("*.mp3") DO (
    CALL :RenameFiles "%%~A" "%%~NXA"
)
GOTO EOF

:RenameFiles
SET fname=%~2
SET renname=%fname:-statement=%
REN "%~1" "%renname%"
GOTO EOF
```

---

**ADD SOMETHING TO THE END OF A RENAMED FILE BEFORE THE FILE NAME EXTENSION**

*(change `fpart` and `mp3path` to match what you need those to be for your usage. The `fpart` is what you need to add and the `mp3path` is the folder where the `MP3` files reside.)*

**NOTE:** *This still assumes the MP3 files have `-statement` in the file name to be stripped out.*

**EXCPLICIT SCRIPT (with parse file name characters)**

```
@ECHO ON

SET mp3path=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
SET fpart=_something

FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /B "%mp3path%\*.mp3"') DO (
    CALL :RenameFiles "%%~FPA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
)
GOTO EOF

:RenameFiles
SET fname=%~2
SET ext=%~3
SET renname=%fname:-statement=%
REN "%~1" "%renname%%fpart%%ext%"
GOTO EOF
```

**EXCPLICIT SCRIPT (no parse just add file name characters)**

```
@ECHO ON

SET mp3path=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
SET fpart=_something

FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /B "%mp3path%\*.mp3"') DO (
    CALL :RenameFiles "%%~FPA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
)
GOTO EOF

:RenameFiles
SET fname=%~2
SET ext=%~3
REN "%~1" "%fname%%fpart%%ext%"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: how about something to the end of finename?