# Batch Script to Bulk Rename Files - Strip off Parenthesis and all Characters between

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-rename

I wish to rename a group of files in a particular folder in such a way that everything **between and including the parenthesis is erased.**

For example a file with the name of:

```
"78 Tax Tips for Canadians for Dummies (ISBN - 0470676582)"
```

I wish to rename it to:

```
"78 Tax Tips for Canadians for Dummies"
```

I need to do this for all the files file in a particular folder for any and all files that follow this same pattern for it's file name characters:

`Dummies (ISBN - .........)`

I tried following and using the batch script logic on this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1006119/remove-a-part-of-a-list-of-names/1006150#1006150) but I could not get that to work the number after the  `ISBN - ##########` part keeps changing with the way I did that incorrectly.

Comment: forgive me but i am not able to figure it out. i request you to give me a command line.

Comment: The link above describes what you want to do with a little bit of tinkering around. That's exactly what you need, a batch script to rename files.

Comment: i am someone who is a stranger to coding. i hope you can understand my position. therefore i need a ready made command line.

Comment: unlike in the link you mentioned, the number after ISBN - '  ' keeps changing, so i am not able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Batch file rename, strip off parenthesis and all characters between, but keep extension**

Save all the logic from the below example to a text file and name it `something.cmd` and then simply execute it. . .

**Script Notes**

- Where `SET RenDir=C:\Path` is `C:\Path`, you'll need to put the full
  path where these files you wish to rename exist.
- The assumption with this script logic is there will ONLY be files in
  the `RenDir` with parenthesis `()` that will need to be stripped with
  the `(ISBN - .........)` type pattern and no other parts of any of
  those file names will contain any parenthesis `()`.

### Example Batch Script Logic

```
@ECHO ON

SET RenDir=C:\Path

FOR /F "DELIMS=() TOKENS=1,3" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%RenDir%\*.*"') DO (
    CALL :RenameFiles "%%~F" "%%~G"
)
GOTO EOF

:RenameFiles
SET fname=%~1
SET Ext=%~2
REN "%RenDir%\%fname%*%ext%" "%fname%%ext%"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: should i copy and paste the entire code in cmd window ?